# What is the word order 'nur dort'

Tags: grammar, phrase, word-order

*Wir haben nur zwei Wochen dort verbracht* - is that right?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to understand more about how it works.

Comment: What is the intended meaning?

Answer (score 3):

I see different possibilities listed in order of my personal preference:

1. Wir haben nur zwei Wochen dort verbracht.
2. Dort haben wir nur zwei Wochen verbracht.
3. Nur zwei Wochen haben wir dort verbracht.
4. Verbracht haben wir dort nur zwei Wochen.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] for remaining questions on how it works. Unfortunately, you answered a question which is probably not going to be considered on-topic in the long run and will be closed soon. Do feel welcome to continue contributing to other questions, though.

Answer (score 1):

That works for me, Laura.

Alternatively: *Dort haben wir nur zwei Wochen verbracht.*

Comment: The alternative does change the priority of the emphasis, tho. By putting the place further up the line, it's receiving more importance.